# Start App On Bootup - Debian

Tags: startup

I have a ts3.desktop file in my /usr/share/applications folder that I want to run on system boot.

I have typed the following commands which don't work

```
crontab -e
```

Then in the editor, I typed

```
@reboot gtk-launch ts3 /usr/share/applications
```

Then I pressed ctrl+o to save it. I reboot and nothing happens, the application doesn't start. What can I do?

UPDATE: After I put these commands in, I did the following command to help you guys with troubleshooting this issue, see below.

```
$ crontab -l
no crontab for server
$ps -ef | grep cron | grep -v grep
root         532      1   0 21:35 ?                 00:00:00 /usr/sbin/cron -f
```

Answer (score 1):

`cron` is not apropriate way to start a desktop application on boot.  You should start that kind of apps after your desktop gets started.

Your desktop environment (GNOME, KDE, etc.) should provide a way for you to configure autostarting in GUI.  Or you might be able to achieve it by just copying `ts3.desktop` to `~/.config/autostart/`, according to [Desktop Application Autostart Specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/autostart-spec/autostart-spec-latest.html).